# displaying two grids side by side on python widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX1Jq.png

We are creating a game of battleships. As displayed on the image provided, we would like each user to have their own start screen. when the start button is pressed, we would like to display 2 separate grids, and then an input box underneath. we are currently using the tkinter function.

so far we have only managed it to display one grid like the one in the image.

This works, however we would appreciate some suggestions on how to display the additional grid:

```
import tkinter  
user1boats: list[list[int]]=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]  

def displaygrid(grid: list[list[int]]):  
    for i in range(len(grid)):  
        Window.columnconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=5)  
        Window.rowconfigure(i, weight=1, minsize=5)  
        for j in range(len(grid[i])):  
            frame = tkinter.Frame(master=Window, borderwidth=0.5)  
            frame.grid(row=i, column=j, padx=3, pady=1)  
            label = tkinter.Label(master=frame, text=str(grid[i][j]))  
            label.pack(padx=3, pady=1)  `
```

Comment: Simply put the grid in a frame, then you can put the two frames with grid inside side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put the *grid* in a frame, then you can create two such frames and put them side by side:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def display_grid(parent, grid: list[list[int]]):
    # create a frame for the grid
    container = tk.Frame(master=parent, bd=2, relief="ridge")
    rows, cols = len(grid), len(grid[0])
    container.rowconfigure(list(range(rows)), weight=1, minsize=5)
    container.columnconfigure(list(range(cols)), weight=1, minsize=5)
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            frame = tk.Frame(master=container, borderwidth=0.5)
            frame.grid(row=i, column=j, padx=3, pady=1)
            label = tk.Label(master=frame, text=grid[i][j])
            label.pack(padx=3, pady=1)
    return container

user1boats: list[list[int]] = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
user2boats = user1boats

root = tk.Tk()
root.config(padx=10, pady=10)

input_frame = tk.Frame(root, height=100, bd=2, relief="ridge")
input_frame.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

# create two frames of grid and put them side by side
grid1 = display_grid(root, user1boats)
grid1.pack(side="left")

grid2 = display_grid(root, user2boats)
grid2.pack(side="left")

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even know side by side..